# Readeonly property in kendo mvc project, and not work when sorting or filtering this column

Tags: model-view-controller, properties, kendo-ui, grid, readonly

I have two table in my database.
first has a id and description and second table has a id, description and first table key, i create a relation between this. after that i create a readonly property in models of second table and get the description of first table by query. i save 100 row of data in second table and 10000 in first table, and each 100 row of first table for one of the row of second table. now when i sort or filter my kendo grid on this column , this take a long time to load! i test this by a more data and see this is not work! i know this in controller whit out read only property but i want to say me a way to use readonly property!! please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but if I understand correctly, it seems you are having problems dealing with large datasets, you may want to look into using [`serverFiltering`](http://www.telerik.com/forums/remote-datasources-and-large-datasets) and [`serverSorting`](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-retrieve-sort-parameters).

Not sure if you have implemented your grid through Razor (`.cshtml`) or client (`.js`) however these links should get you on the right track.

A few more tutorial links:

[Razor](http://www.decisivedata.net/blog/server-side-paging-sorting-and-filtering-using-the-kendo-ui-grid-and-entity-framework-code-first)

[Javascript](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/675879/An-Example-to-Use-Kendo-Grid)